# Transition ease on object that shows on hover

Tags: css, hover, transition

I'm trying to get the transition ease to work on this, but can't. It's a bit trickier to know where to put the transition css when it's targeting something that shows something on hover.

The code is:

```
<div class="language-box">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="call-cs">English
      <span class="cs">Coming Soon</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Svenska</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And css I'm trying is:

```
span.cs {
    display: none;
}
a.call-cs:hover span.cs {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #4E4E4E;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    left: 31px;
    top: -20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;

    -webkit-transition: background 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 3s ease;
    -o-transition: background 3s ease;
    transition: background 3s ease;
}
```

Comment: You cannot transition the `display` property - you might want to look at [**This Article**](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/G9yyx/ ?? - @Myj

Answer (score 0):

You can't use transition for display, but change size of your li and it's opacity to create cool transition:

CSS

```
    span.cs {
    opacity:0;
    height:0;
}
a.call-cs:hover span.cs {
    display: block;
    height:18px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #4E4E4E;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    left: 31px;
    top: -20px;
    opacity:1;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;

   transition: all 0.5s ease;

}

li{
    position:relative;

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/zvG4L/1/)